# Test for device using udev sysname

Tags: c, udev

I'm writing my first ever C program in Ubuntu and it involves detecting when the AC adapter or Battery on my laptop see events (through `udev_monitor`). So far, I'm able to log to the console when the power situation changes using something like this `while` snippet:

```
while (1) {
    dev = udev_monitor_receive_device(mon);
    if (dev) {
        printf("\n[INFO] Got Device\n");
        printf(" [INFO] Device Name: %s\n", udev_device_get_sysname(dev));
...
```

And that's great! When I plug or unplug my laptop I get that logged to the console. However, what I'm failing to grok is how to conditionally test using these same functions.

For instance, this is never true:

```
if (udev_device_get_sysname(dev) == "ADP1") { ... }
```

I'm unsure how to properly test this. Obviously it prints as a string (array of characters?) when `printf()` and `%s` are used.

EDIT: The values logged to the consle from the function called are `ADP1` for the adapter and `BAT0` for the battery - which correlates to their entries in the /sys/class/ directory.

Comment: use `strcmp` to comape strings in c

Comment: in `C` string comparisons use `strcmp`/`strncmp`, otherwise you're comparing the pointer values, which won't be the same

Comment: Is it really that simple? I'm really unused to how strings work in C. I'll give it a shot - thanks!

Comment: btw, does ``udev_monitor_receive_device`` blocks your thread? I believe, not, so you are doing *busy wait* waisting your CPU cycles and power

Comment: @user996142 Yeah, there is a non-blocking solution, but I wanted to fully understand my program before implementing another optimization.

Comment: Hey @Petesh - please add this as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you compare strings using one of the string comparison routines, such as [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) or [`strncmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html). If you compare them using `==` you're only comparing the values of the pointers, which will not be the same.

So for the code checking the sysname is incorrect, as the pointer comparison will never be true. It should be changed to something like:

```
if (strcmp(udev_device_get_sysname(dev), "ADP1") == 0) { … }
```

which causes it to compare the strings, rather than the pointer values.

Comment: Thanks! Pointers are a whole new world for me; the answer was deceptively simple. My custom screen dimming app is now working like a charm!